# Freeware Backup utility - with shadow copy ability?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, backup

I search for a free software that can use Shadow Copy.

In XP I can use Cobian, but in Win2008/x64 that Shadow Copy cannot accessable.

With Windows Backup I have problem that I have only one HDD.

Cobian can create zip backups, and can copy to ftp, but Windows Backup do this only different HDD...

Thanks for your every help:
   dd

---

From Cobian FAQ:

Q: I cannot create a VSS snapshot or cannot use Volume Shadow Copies at all. Why?

There are several things that could cause the VSS to fail when creating a snapshot. The main problem could be permissions. The user that is executing the backup must have administration's or backup privileges to use VSS.

Then the volume that you are trying to snapshot must be supported by the system: It must be a NTFS volume (not FAT or FAT32), local (not on a remote machine) and native (not a TrueCrypt volume or some other emulated volume)

Cobian Backup is a 32 bit application and, on 64 bit systems it must run under WOW64. This works fine on XP64 or Windows Server 2003 64 because 32 bit programs are allowed to call VSS from WOW64.

Vista and Windows Server 2008 don't allow that and VSS must be called as a native 64 bit application, which means that you can't use VSS from Cobian Backup on Vista 64 at this moment. A solution for this issue could be found in the future.

Comment: Give PING a look see...http://ping.windowsdream.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Cobian Backup v10](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm) works on Windows 7.

Comment: I added the FAQ question. You can see what I experienced: Shadow Copy don't working there...

Comment: I tried FBackup too, but I have problem to run as Scheduled Job - terminated... From batch file it is working, but when I trying to run in the background, it is not working...

Comment: Permissions? See if you can run it as Administrator or at a System Service level...

Comment: Cobian FAQ wrote that Cobian not supports these os-s. I gave rights to the service, but it is dying at start.

Comment: Ah damn, then i'm all outta ideas :(

Answer (score 0):

[Macrium Reflect](http://www.macrium.com/) is a backup and disk imaging software program for Microsoft Windows developed by Paramount Software UK Ltd in 2006. It creates disk images and file backup archives using Microsoft Volume Shadow Copy Service to ensure 'point in time' data accuracy.
There is [free edition](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx) of software.